# Adding alpha to a derived or defined colour in JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx

In JavaFX CSS I can do construct a colour by defining it as either RGB or RGBA, e.g. `-fx-red-color: #FF0000FF;` or deriving it from another colour, e.g. `-fx-lighter-red-color: derive(-fx-red-color, 50%);`

How can I change the alpha channel in a defined or derived colour?

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

You can't. The alpha channel is not used for defining colors, but for transparency. You need a workaround.

**Solution:**

If you want the transparent part to appear in a specific color, you must define that color as the background color of your component. This way, the background color will be shown in the transparent areas of the components above.